# COALESCE inside SQL Server Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I have a table "Tasks" that can have multiple users assigned to it, stored in table "Assignment".

I have q COALESCE query that groups my users into one string:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names, '') + taskAssignment.FullName + '; '
FROM dbo.v_TaskAssignment taskAssignment
WHERE (taskAssignment.TaskId = @TaskId) 
  AND taskAssignment.AssignmentIsRemoved = 'False' 
  AND taskAssignment.FullName IS NOT NULL

SELECT @Names as Names
```

And my query for the tasks:

```
SELECT Id, Summary
FROM dbo.v_Task
```

I want my task query to have one more string column listing all my users delimited by a semi colon. However this does not seem to work:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT        
    dbo.v_Task.Id, dbo.v_Task.Summary, 
    (SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names, '') + taskAssignment.FullName + ';'
     FROM dbo.v_TaskAssignment taskAssignment
     WHERE (taskAssignment.TaskId = dbo.v_Task.Id) 
       AND taskAssignment.AssignmentIsRemoved = 'False' 
       AND taskAssignment.FullName IS NOT NULL
     SELECT @Names as Names) AS Assignements
FROM
    dbo.v_Task 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.v_TaskAssignment ON dbo.v_Task.Id = dbo.v_TaskAssignment.TaskId
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

How can I go about and get my Coalesce query inside my task select query?

Comment: what o/p r getting with ur query??

Comment: Nothing, the query has an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, how about a somewhat simple method with `XML PATH`?

```sql
SELECT Id, Summary, STUFF(
  (SELECT ';' + FullName 
   FROM v_TaskAssignment ta
   WHERE t.Id = ta.TaskId
     AND ta.AssignmentIsRemoved = 'False' 
     AND ta.FullName IS NOT NULL
   FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') Assignments
FROM dbo.v_Task t
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd3c4/15).

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! However, I'm curious, would you know why my COALESCE inside the SELECT doesn't work?

Comment: @LanFeusT One thing is that the select you're using are two entirely separate queries, while a subquery can only contain a single one. I'm also unsure about the use of variables in the subquery, but that I can't really tell for sure in which forms it is/isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE would work here - something like this maybe

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000)
```

;WITH Naming (Id, Names, Name)
AS
(
SELECT 
    t.Id
    ,COALESCE(@Names, '') + ta.FullName + ';'
    ,Name 
FROM
    dbo.v_taskAssignment tA
JOIN
    dbo.v_Task t
ON
    ta.TaskId = t.Id
)

SELECT
     T.Id, 
     T.Summary,
     Names,
     Name
FROM
    Naming N
JOIN
    v_Task T
ON
    N.Id = T.Id